# Get values of multiple inputs with JQuery/Javascript and Filestack buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner so I need some help with this, I'm building a modal with a select and filestack button where I select an option and upload a file, but I also have an option called "Add" for append more select and buttons looking like this:

[image]

So I tried this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="lsttrad">
<select class="form-control" name="astr[]" id="astr" style="margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:5px;">
<option value="test">test test</option>
<option value="test1">test1 test1</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="filet">UPLOAD FILES</button>
</div>
<a id="add" style="cursor:pointer;">Add</a>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="asign">OK</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
//add more select and filestack button
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.filestackapi.com/v3/filestack.js"></script>
<script>
$('#add').click(function(){
$("#lsttrad").append('<select class="form-control" name="astr[]" id="astr" style="margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:5px;">'+
'<option value="test">test test</option>'+
'<option value="test1">test1 test1</option>'+
'</select><button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="filet">UPLOAD FILES</button>');
});

//Filestack button
$("#filet").click(function(){

        var client = filestack.init('myAPI');
        client.pick({
          fromSources: ['local_file_system','googledrive','gmail','facebook','dropbox','onedrive','webcam'],
          lang: 'es',
          maxFiles: 100
        }).then(function(Blobs) {

          var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Blobs));            
          var displayedUrls = "";
          var displayedFilename = "";
          var out = "";
          var icon = "";
          for (i = 0; i < result.filesUploaded.length; i++) {

            out += '<a target=_blank href=' + result.filesUploaded[i].url + '>' + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' +  result.filesUploaded[i].filename + '</button></a>';                    
             $('#lsttrad').append('<div id="filest" style="display:inline-block;margin-left:5px;">'+ out +'<textarea style="display:none;" name="link[]">'+out+'</textarea></div>');

            }
        });
});

</script>
```

The problem is:

**1)** When I want to upload files it doesn't work using the other filestack buttons and when I add more inputs I would be able to upload files for each input added looking like this:

[image]

I tried changing to:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="filet[]">UPLOAD FILES</button>
```

and in JQuery:

```
$("input[name='filet[]'").click(...)
```

But it doesn't work.

**2)** I want to display select and hidden textarea values in a alert clicking OK button like this:

> test : docfile.docx
>
> test1 : docfile.docx

So I tried this:

```
$("#asign").click(function(){
    var inps = document.getElementsByName('astr[]');
    var inps2 = document.getElementsByName('link[]');
    var inp='';
    var inp2='';

    for (var i = 0; i <inps.length; i++) {
        inp+=inps[i]; 
    }

    for (var u = 0; u <inps2.length; u++) {
        inp2+=inps2[u]; 
    }
    alert(inp.value+":"+inp2.value);
});
```

But it shows:

> undefined:undefined

I would like some help.

Comment: I updated your question by adding the code snippet and as you can see in the error of the console your `filestack` is not defined. If `filestack` exists in your source code please update the question with it - otherwise you need to fix this.

Comment: @messerbill Of course my filestack exists and it's defined, I just put it in this way as an example to suppose is defined and working

Comment: pls add it here too

Comment: @messerbill Now I modified it.